# What does "SELECT X=[column] FROM [table] exactly does"?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I wanted to set a variable in SQL by

```
SELECT @myVariable=myColumn FROM myTable WHERE ...
```

But by mistake I wrote it without @

```
SELECT myVariable=myColumn FROM myTable WHERE ...
```

It seems that it is valid, there isn't any error in syntax, although variable of course isn't set.

So what does such instruction exactly do?

Comment: It is treated as a column-alias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sets `myVariable` as an alias for `myColumnn`.  It's essentially the same as:

```
Select  MyColumn As MyVariable
From    MyTable
Where   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right that it is valid syntax and it names the output column as `myVariable` and populates the column with the content of `myColumn`.